# How can I make context menus in Google Maps not get hidden by context menus in Firefox?

Tags: context-menu, firefox, google-maps, firefox-3.6

Google Maps provides a useful context menu — AKA right click menu — within its map area. When I visit Google Maps with Firefox 3.6 or Firefox 4, I have a hard time accessing that menu because my right clicks cause Firefox's own context menu to open above Google Maps's.

This is the same problem that is described, with screenshots, [at this forum thread](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r22872923-FireFox-Google-maps-rightclick-hidden).

Is there a way to make these two menus not interfere with each other, and if so, what is it? The forum only suggests the <kbd>Esc</kbd> workaround I was already using and am not satisfied with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually caused by "Disable or replace context menus" option being unchecked under Options -> Content -> Advanced... next to JavaScript.  Meaning, you have to allow JavaScript to "disable or replace context menus".

I realize it sounds scary; but that's what usually causes the double-context menu, since the site's JavaScript has to disable the browser's context menu to display the site's context menu upon a right-click.

Comment: An easier way: `shift`+`right-click` will bring up the context menu in Firefox when the website is trying to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-technical work-around; it works for me, it isn't brilliant, but is does the job without resorting to technical changes. It's all done with the mouse:

Right-click in Google Maps where you want the Google context menu to appear. Context menus for Firefox and Google appear; Firefox is on top, but you want Google's. Now, the first important bit: *without moving your mouse*, press & *hold down* the right mouse button (and keep it held down).

The Firefox context menu should disappear and the Google context menu should remain. With the right mouse button still held down, move the mouse cursor over the Google context menu to the option you want to invoke. Again, whilst *still keeping the right mouse button down*, left-click the desired Google context menu item you want.

Now let go of your mouse buttons and, hopefully, you get the Google action you desire! Left-click Google Maps to remove any naughty dangling context menus.

Comment: Wouldn't the escape key workaround provided in the question be easier?

Answer (score 0):

Good answer!
What I found that works in my case, is almost similar to your answer, but even a little more straightforward:

1. I right-click, and the Firefox right-click menu appears,
2. WITHOUT MOVING THE CURSOR, I only right-click again, and the Google context menu replaces the Firefox one.
3. The second right-click is done about 2 seconds after the first one and is a definite second click, not a double click as is typically done.